# Looking for a typing tutor app

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, macbook-pro

Years ago, I learned typing by a program named Typing Tutor, on DOS. XD

Now, my son is using a MacBook and I am teaching him how to type. What software/website you recommend to learn typing on a MacBook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [**Typist**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/typist/id415166115?mt=12)

Typist is a great free app for learning to type, and whilst it's not going to win any design awards, it's great at what it does, especially for free.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**[The Typing Cat](http://thetypingcat.com)**

[image]

I like it because:

- it's free
- fast
- gives nice progress
- supports multiple layouts (qwerty, dvorak, colemak, workman)
- looks good
- You don't need to install anything - it's webapp
- i'm creator and i'm proud of it and made it as sideeffect of teaching myself Colemak. But I can be subjective u need to try it yourself to verify my statements :)

Answer (score 0):

### [TypeQuick](http://www.typequick.com/)

I learned to type in Australia 20+ years ago using software called TypeQuick, while I was in high school.

They are still around, and do their software. They now provide an on on-line course specifically for kids.

The price is [AU$30](http://www.typequick.com/about-typequick-online).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Master Key](http://macinmind.com/?area=app&app=masterkey&pg=info) to practice typing some plain text books. It's shareware and you'll have to buy a license to unlock some of the lessons though.

[image]