# Looking for Mac Typing software that supports Spanish keyboard layouts - Recommendations?

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, software

I've moved from Windows to the Mac a while ago, and in this "self-improvement" path, I've also realized that I need to learn to touch-type (I can do around 50-60 WPM with 3-and-a-half fingers, but I need more).

I'm a Spanish speaker so I need to learn on a Spanish keyboard. I've already seen the answer to a similar question here ([Looking for a typing tutor app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112793/looking-for-a-typing-tutor-app)) but all the answers offered assume English keyboards

I'm looking for a more "guided" learning approach.

Comment: If you just need to practice, isn't something like [Typeracer](http://play.typeracer.com/?universe=lang_es) an option?

Comment: Hi, @Mathias711. I'm looking for a more "guided" learning approach, but thanks a million for the link, I'll certainly save it to test my skills as I go along!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this is what you are looking for](http://www.cursomeca.com/leccion1.htm?v=889938926889881894883902899888961898938926889881894883902899888961890938950961):

[image: spanish]